# Add container #id to .load('$(this).attr("href"));

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pull only a specific div from the page my link is pointing to.

My links are formatted like this : `<a href="about-smith.asp" class="pic">img</a>`

```
$(function(){
        $("a.pic").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#subsidebar").load($(this).attr("href") + "#subcontent");
         });
    });
```

And I want that to pull only the #subcontent div from about-smith.asp. It's displaying the content in the #subsidebar div, but it's the *entire* page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a space between the url and the selector:

```
$("#subsidebar").load($(this).attr("href") + " #subcontent");
                                              ^
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I knew I had to be overlooking something pretty basic. I'll accept the answer as soon as the engine allows me to.